# How should this Ansible variable be defined?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to make sense of a variable reference I found in an incomplete Ansible role. The role references a value using

```
dest: “{{params['box'].t1}}”
```

In a separate yaml file I have

```
box:
    t1: "Albany"
    t2: "Albuquerque"
```

params isn't defined, so obviously this isn't going to work, but I can't figure out the correct way to define it. **Can someone tell me where (or how) params must be defined for this variable reference to work in Ansible?**

---

Related questions. Does the use of square brackets in `dest: “{{params['box'].t1}}”` indicate that it is a dictionary? If yes, could I also write this as `dest: “{{params['box']['t1']}”` or `dest: “{{params.box.t1}”`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params['box'].t1` refers to `Albany` in:

```
params:
  box:
    t1: "Albany"
    t2: "Albuquerque"
```

It is the same as `params.box.t1` and `params['box']['t1']`.

Brackets refer to a key name, so they imply it is a dictionary.

---

You typically use square bracket-notation when you want to refer to a key via a variable:

```
vars:
  wanted_key: box
  params:
    box:
      t1: Albany
    other:
      t1: Albuquerque
```

Then `params[wanted_key].t1` refers to `Albany`.

In your example the value inside square brackets is a string (quoted), so all above examples are equivalent.

Comment: using params: was actually the first thing I tried, but because I had incorrectly spaced the yaml file, it hadn't worked. Thank you for the great explanation and for saving me from my silly mistake!!!